# MATLAB: Use Logical indexing to replace the values in the matrix by its value divided by 2?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, indexing

So I have a matrix A. And I can find the values of greater than 7 with logical indexing of A>7.

How can I then, replace all the values of A>7 by the numbers divided by 2?

I tried:

```
    A(A>7) = [num1/2, num2/2, etc]
```

But I'd want the math done without me inputting the nums/2 values to be replaced accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by using the same indices likes the following:

```
indices = A > 7;
A(indices) = A(indices)/2;
```